# Bot Framework Error: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘0’

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

Sometimes my bot return the message: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘0’ it is not always, and only in prod. Any help?

Comment: Could you add your sample code and point out where and exactly when it occurs?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of responses occur when some exception occurs and is not handled. For example you are interacting with database and you got some error writing to db.